# Capture key press event using NSNotificationCenter

Tags: iphone, keyboard, keypress, nsnotificationcenter

this solution
[Receive iPhone keyboard events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267560/iphone-keyboard-event)

offers a way to capture the keypress event using notification center.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(keyPressed:) name: UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object: nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(keyPressed:) name: UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification object: nil];

........

-(void) keyPressed: (NSNotification*) notification
{
  NSLog([[notification object]text]);
}
```

It works ok, but for every key that is been pressed from the keyboard the keyPressed function gets called 3 times.

Is this normal or am i doing something wrong?

Teo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification should only appear once per key pressed. At least that is what I get when testing. The only thing I can think of is that you are calling `addObserver:selector:name:object:` three times.

Perhaps you are doing it in several view controllers and forget to call `removeObserver:name:object:`?

Or you are calling `addObserver:selector:name:object:` in a function that gets called several times? `viewDidLoad` is normally a good place to put code like this.

Comment: I was the addObserver from the viewDidLoad function but the controller was initialized 3 times for 3 different instances.